# Using GetAwaiting with unique class attribute is raising error in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Dears, I am trying to use a unique index class attribute to prevent application to save save data

```
public class Ports
{
    public short PortsID { get; set; }

    [Required] [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR")][StringLength(10)] [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Remote("IsPortExist", "Ports", AdditionalFields = "PortsID",
            ErrorMessage = "Port name already exists")]
    public string Portname { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    //[InverseProperty("POL")]
    //public virtual ICollection<RateRequests> Portofloading { get; set; }

    //[InverseProperty("POD")]
    //public virtual ICollection<RateRequests> Portofdischarge { get; set; }
}

public async Task<JsonResult> IsPortExist(string PortName, int? Id)
    {
        bool isPortExist = await db.ports.Any(x => x.Portname == PortName && x.PortsID != Id);

        return Json(!isPortExist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the error is 'bool' doesnot contain a definition for a 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'Getawaiter' accepting a first argument of type bool could be found, note i am using frame work 4.6.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line

```
bool isPortExist = await db.ports.Any(x => x.Portname == PortName && x.PortsID != Id);
```

Any is not an async method, you will have to use its async version AnyAsync. Please change the code to

```
bool isPortExist = await db.ports.AnyAsync(x => x.Portname == PortName && x.PortsID != Id);
```